# Using srun outside SLURM

Tags: bash, slurm

I have a code that is usually run under SLURM. Something like

```
if ! lengthy_command
then
    echo "Error occured"
fi
```

For accounting purposes, I would like to move to a `srun` based launch of the command:

```
if ! srun <srun params> lengthy_command
then
    echo "Error occured"
fi
```

But after changing that line, the script will no longer run in an interactive session (outside SLURM). Is there any way to generalize the script so it can run under both conditions? I cannot see anything in the `srun` documentation that points in that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a variable and set it to `srun` when in a job (for instance when `$SLURM_JOBID` is set), and to leave it empty otherwise.

```
if [ -n $SLURM_JOBID ] ;  
then 
LAUNCH=srun <srun params>
else
LAUNCH=
fi

if ! $LAUNCH lengthy_command
then
    echo "Error occured"
fi
```

This approach can be extended by setting `LAUNCH` to `parallel <parallel options>`  when using GNU parallel, or to other commands when run in a cluster with another scheduler.

Another option is to create a Bash function named `srun` that encapsulates the logic (untested):

```
srun() {
if [ -n $SLURM_JOBID ] ;  
then 
command srun $@
else
$@
fi
}
```

Comment: That is a good approach, but still have some drawbacks. The main one is that the `srun` parameters will change from one invocation to the next on the same script. And having to add a conditional before every command makes it quite different from a 'drop-in' replacement (in case `srun` does not support this kind of conditional execution). I'm preparing a bash function to try to solve this, but still have some problems... a new question is coming.

Comment: Then you need to make a version of `srun` for when running out of Slurm, using a Bash function or a script with precedence in the PATH over the actual `srun` command

Comment: Yes, I'm going the bash function way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217555/srun-drop-in-replacement